# Office 2016 does not activate

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

I just bought Office 2016 Standard edition. I installed it, ran Windows Update to get the latest patches and now I want to activate Office.

In the activation dialog I can either login to an account having a license or enter the product key.

I enter the product key, Office accepts it but the next time I start Office it asks me again for the key. But I did not get any error entering the key.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding all patches **before** activating Office seems to lead to errors. Do the following:

1. De-install Office
2. Install Office
3. Start an Office application, like for instance Word
4. Activate it with your Product Key
5. Close Word
6. Run Windows Update to get the latest version of your Office suite

Answer (score 2):

I've run into something like this before. If you were using a trial or pre-installed version of Office that came with your PC, the key that it used is still stored by Windows even after installing the full version. You'll need to remove the old key before using the new one.

1. Open command prompt
2. Navigate to your Office installation folder, likely `C:Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16` or `C:Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16`
3. Enter `cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus` to see a list of currently-installed keys
4. Identify the old key
5. Enter `cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:value` where "value" is the last five characters of the previous key
6. You might want to use `cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus` again to ensure that any old keys have been successfully removed

Once you do this, you shouldn't have trouble activating Office with your new key.

Also see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/tools-to-manage-volume-activation-of-office

Answer (score -1):

**We can view if the Office 2016 is activated:**

1.First create a new Word document on the desktop.

2.Double-click the document to open it.

3.Click on the file in the top left corner of the document.

4.The account selected in the drop-down menu.

5.At this point, you can see if your version of Office is active on the right side.

[image]

**The following is troubleshoot ways:**

If the office 2016 is activated, we try to reinstalled it, and reactivate it.

if the office 2016 is not activated, we can reactivate it according to the way in following link.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activate-office-365-office-2016-or-office-2013-5bd38f38-db92-448b-a982-ad170b1e187e

If there is still a problem after reactivation, there may be a problem with the activation key.